Проблема с получением ответа от сервера в клиент-серверном приложении для Android yf java
Пишу клиент-сервер с сервером на java и клиентом на Android'е. Использую стандартные socket'ы. При передаче данных в строковом формате через BufferedWriter/Reader или DataOutputWriter/Reader проблем не возникает. Решил попробовать побайтовую передачу, так как хочу передавать файлы. Столкнулся с проблемой, что от клиента к серверу все приходит и сервер успешно все отрабатывает, но обратно клиенту ответ не приходит. Клиент падает с ошибкой socket close. Иные решения и библиотеки на данный момент не рассматриваю. Необходимо понять, что я делаю не так в рамках текущей концепции.
Сервер:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String response = "_";

        String request = "";
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
            System.out.println("Server start");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number. ");
        }
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = null;
            InputStream reader = null;
            InputStream reader2 = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't accept client connection. ");
            }

            try {
                reader = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream. ");
            }
            try {
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("File not found. ");
            }

                System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
                    try {
                        byte[] bytes_request = new byte[64];
                        byte[] bytes_response = new byte[64];
                        int name;
                        while ((name = reader.read(bytes_request)) > 0) {
                            reader.read(bytes_request, 0, 64);
                            request = new String(bytes_request, "utf-8").trim();
                        }

                        System.out.println(request);
                        try {
                            switch (request) {

                               //Здесь логика на формирование response;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        int count;
                        reader2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        while ((count = reader2.read(bytes_response)) > 0) {
                              String str = new String(bytes_response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();
                              System.out.println(str.trim());
                            out.write(bytes_response, 0, count);
                        }
                        out.close();
                        reader.close();
                        reader2.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
            socket.close();
        }
}

}
Клиент:
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class ServerClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

String localhost = "127.0.0.1";

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
    String message = "_" + voids[0];
    byte[] byt_file = null;
    byte[] byt = null;
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(localhost, 4444);

        byte[] byte_request = new byte[256];
        byte[] byte_response = new byte[256];

        InputStream in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

        int count;

        while ((count = in2.read(byte_request)) > 0) {
            out.write(byte_request, 0, count);
        }
        in2.close();
        out.close();

        try {
            Log.i("CheckError123", String.valueOf(socket.isConnected()) );
            while ((count = in.read(byte_response)) > 0) {
                response = new String(byte_response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
            Log.i("CheckError123", response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("CheckError123", "error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        in.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

}
Сервер обрабатывает и передает response но в клиенте InputStream ничего не принимает, а сокет закрывается.
Ошибка в клиенте:
2024-11-29 17:23:42.793 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W  java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:114)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:351)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:180)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:172)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:335)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:400)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at com.example.appoper.ServerClient.doInBackground(ServerClient.java:157) 
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at com.example.appoper.ServerClient.doInBackground(ServerClient.java:27)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2024-11-29 17:23:42.796 20842-20912 System.err              com.example.appoper                  W      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)

